# Node js and socket.io not have any error but not work when access by url, how can i do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Node js and socket.io not have any error but not work when access by url, how can i do ?

My step to install is

1. `cd /home/admin/web/my-doamin-name/public_html`
2. `npm init`
3. `npm install --save express socket.io`
4. `node app.js`

...............................................................

After call node app.js, it's will show

```
start server on port :3000
```

...........................................................

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.php');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('start server on port :3000');
});
```

.......................................................

index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>HELLO WORLD</body>
</html>
```

.......................................................

When i test telnet on port 3000 by this command line

```
telnet my-domain-name.com 3000
```

It's show like this.

```
Trying xxx.xx.x.xxx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xx.x.xxx: Connection refused
```

.......................................................

And i test port 3000 by this command line

```
ss -nltp|grep :3000
```

But it's not show anything.

.......................................................

And then i tried to access to mysite (on google chrome)

```
https://www.my-domain-name.com:3000
```

In google chrome it's show error

```
This site can’t be reached
```

How can i do ?

Comment: that means your server is not running

Comment: @George Bailey -- how to check it's ?

Comment: follow https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html  to create server. And make sure you have ports open  you mention for server

Comment: When call node `app.js` it's show `Example app listening on port 3000!` When access `https://www.my-domain.com:3000` still show `This site can’t be reached` on google chrome sir.

Comment: have you added `www.my-domain.com = 127.0.0.1` in your host file if you are using windows ? or just test it with `localhost:3000`

Comment: i was test in vps sir.